# What is the clear liquid expelled when a lycanthrope shifts?

Tags: anita-blake, laurell-k-hamilton, werewolf

In the [Anita Blake Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anita_Blake%3a_Vampire_Hunter) lycanthropes of all kinds exist. When they shift forms, they expel a clear thick fluid that somehow manages to get on everything nearby but them (they somehow remain dry during the process).

What is this fluid?

Answer (score 1):

I've been through the books and I've been unable to find any canon description of the precise *nature* of the [bodily fluids](http://uk.ask.com/question/what-are-types-of-body-fluids) that are being expelled, nor why there's such a great temperature generated during the process.

Given that it's repeatedly described as a hot/clear/viscous bodily fluid, the obvious choices are  [blood plasma](http://www.cafleurebon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/blood-plasma.jpg), [intracellular fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstitial_fluid) or [serous fluid](http://www.nhsdirect.wales.nhs.uk/encyclopaedia/b/article/blisters/) but frankly, none are especially suitable given that they're variously yellow or red. I think we can simply assign this to the other-worldly nature of the shapeshifting seen in the novels. If we apply real world physics to the transformation process, then we'll tie ourselves in knots.

Comment: Never read the books, but the fluid sounds very much like **ectoplasm**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectoplasm_%28paranormal%29 We **are** dealing with the supernatural here.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - Since it's specifically described as a "bodily fluid", that's the tack I've taken